# Run a broadcast "adb connect" to all devices in the network

Tags: android, networking, adb, broadcast, broadcasting

I have many android devices in my network, all with same port 5555 open for adb.
To connect to a specific device, knowing the specific IP inside of the network I simply run this line of code:

```
adb connect 192.168.43.1
```

What if I want to try to connect to all devices in one shot? Is there a way to send this command in broadcast without trying to launch it for every single possible IP.
The devices in my specific case are ~100, even if I have the list of IPs I would prefer to find a way to send it in broadcast so I can automatically catch if a new device is added to the network without manually updating the list.

Comment: adb uses TCP which can not be "broadcasted".

Comment: check https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/161244414